# Writing enlarged fractional exponents

Tags: fractions

I'm not able to write enlarged fractional exponents. For that purpose, '\frac' gives too small exponents, and '\dfrac' gives too large ones.

`$x^{\dfrac{12}{7}}-x^{\dfrac{5}{7}}$`

This yields:

[image]

But I want slightly better positioned exponents, like:

[image: Slightly better positioned exponents]

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome! Do you think that this would be clearer to a reader than `x^{12/7}`?

Comment: If you don't like either sizes, then may be you can adjust the font size manually, i.e. use '\small' or '\large' commands before the fraction exponent.

Comment: @hesham erh, no, you cannot use `\small` in math mode. You need to use trickery like what Steven shows.

Comment: Thanks @daleif. You're right. Then what about using \scalebox?

Comment: @hesham `\scalebox` switches to text, so no much different than Stevens solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,mathtools}
\newcommand\specfrac[2]{%
  \abovebaseline[-1pt]{\hbox{\small$\dfrac{#1}{#2}$}}}
\begin{document}
$x^{\specfrac{12}{7}}-x^{\specfrac{5}{7}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change `\small` to `\scriptsize`, then

[image]